# losing TR onclick action after calling AJAX the second time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I would like to do is call the PHP file which creates a table but I'm not that familiar with JQuery.  Please help.  I'm losing the onclick and the highlighting that I have in the TR after calling the AJAX the second time.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'save-all.php',
    async: false,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg == 'true') {
            $.get('orgs-list.php', {}, function (data) {
                $('#tbl-content1').replaceWith($(data));
                $("#success").show().fadeOut(3000);
            });
        } else {
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(3000);
        } //end #msg==true
    } //end #success
}); //end #ajax
```

And the PHP file:

```
$stid = oci_parse($connection, 'SELECT org_id, agency, pobox, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, realty_organizations.org_type AS org_type, realty_orgtype.org_type AS agencytype
FROM wflhd_admin.realty_organizations, wflhd_admin.realty_orgtype 
    WHERE realty_organizations.org_type = realty_orgtype.typeid
        ORDER BY agency'); 
oci_execute($stid);
$nrows = oci_fetch_all($stid, $res, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);   
?>
<table id='tbl-content1' cellpadding='3' width='100%' cellspacing='0' border='1' style='font-family:verdana; font-size: 11px;' >

<?              
for ($i=0; $i<=$nrows; $i++) {?>    
<tr id="row_<? echo $res[$i]['ORG_ID']; ?>" onClick="DoNavOrg('<? echo $res[$i]['ORG_ID']; ?>','<? echo $res[$i]['AGENCY'] ?>','<? echo $res[$i]['POBOX'] ?>','<? echo $res[$i]['ADDRESS1']; ?>','<? echo $res[$i]['ADDRESS2']; ?>','<? echo $res[$i]['CITY']; ?>','<? echo $res[$i]['STATE']; ?>','<? echo $res[$i]['ZIPCODE']; ?>','<? echo $res[$i]['ORG_TYPE']; ?>'); return false;">   
}
```

Comment: Can you also post `DoNavOrg` so we can see what happens when that's called?

Comment: @Archer that is a messy one :)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Isn't it!  Not the worst though :p

Comment: @Archer probably should recommend event delegation??

Comment: is there any error in the browser console

Comment: Don't use `onclick` attributes but rather assign a class to your `TR` and use `data` attributes and non-obstructive JS such as `$(document).on('click', $('tr.clickableRow'), function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like you have it the first time because onDocumentReady the first TR is binded as an DOM element, and that's why jQuery is picking it up.

After you add HTML/DOM elements dynamically, you should BIND them to the functionality you need, with .bind()
http://api.jquery.com/bind/

So try do to something like this,

```
    $( ".your-newly-added-tr" ).bind( "click", function() {
        // call what ever you need, "DoNavOrg" or anything else... 
    });
```

Hope it helps. :)